# Which Firefox version is compatible with Selenium 3.6.0

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I would like to update the Selenium version 3.6.0 and I was wondering which is the best version of FF to use if Gecko driver is not used?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

## Selenium with Gecko Driver

### Selenium Release Perspective :

Selenium v3.6.0 (Java) Release explicitly didn't mention any dependency explicitly.

The last dependency explicitly mentioned by Selenium was for v3.4.0 which is as follows :

```
Geckodriver 0.16 is strongly recommended
```

### GeckoDriver Release Perspective :

1. **`GeckoDriver v0.19.0`**: Firefox 55.0 (and greater) & Selenium 3.5 (and greater)
2. **`GeckoDriver v0.18.0`**: Firefox 53.0 (and greater)
3. **`GeckoDriver v0.16.0`**: Selenium 3.4 (and greater)

### Mozilla Firefox Versions :

Ideally, each **`Selenium`** release should support each version of **`Mozilla Firefox`** releases (starting with Firefox 48.x) where the property **`"marionette"`** needs to be set to **`true`** (either by **default** or through **configuration**) as follows:

```
cap = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
cap["marionette"] = True
```

If you are working with the legacy **`Firefox`** releases (till **Firefox 47.x**) **`GeckoDriver`** still works but you have to explicitly set the property **`"marionette"`** to **`false`** as follows:

```
cap = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
cap["marionette"] = False
```

---

### [*GeckoDriver*, *Selenium* and *Firefox Browser* compatibility chart](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/geckodriver/Support.html)

[image: supported_platforms_geckodriver_24]

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use GeckoDriver if you want to run your scripts in Firefox versions greater than 47.0.1. Firefox 47.0.1 and before would not need GeckoDriver.

Answer (score 1):

source: http://www.automationtestinghub.com/selenium-3/

> You would need to use GeckoDriver if you want to run your scripts in Firefox versions greater than 47.0.1. Firefox 47.0.1 and before would not need GeckoDriver