# Selenium does not work perfectly

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

This runs perfectly:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox().get('https://www.facebook.com')
```

But this gives an error:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.facebook.com')
```

> WebDriverException: Message: Failed to decode response from marionette

Comment: Hmm. That's odd. Can you provide the full code as well as the entire traceback message? It may also be helpful to know the version of the firefox driver you are using.

Comment: Cheak out version compatibility from this QA - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47073748/which-firefox-version-is-compatible-with-selenium-3-6-0/47095220#47095220

Comment: Please share the entire error log