# Gecko driver Synchronisation issue

Tags: selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

Do we have a stable gecko driver/Firfeox/selenium version combination.

I was using
selenium version - 2.53
Firefox version - 46
My scripts were working fine without any issues.

Currently I am using 
selenium version - 3.6.0
Firefox version - 56.0.1
Gecko Driver - 0.19.0

But i am getting lot of synchronization issues.Some were not fixed after adding explicit wait.I believe this is due to using external driver(Gecko).
Can anyone suggest if we have a stable version combination which gives minimum synchronization issues.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which Firefox version is compatible with Selenium 3.6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47073748/which-firefox-version-is-compatible-with-selenium-3-6-0)