# Webdriver For Firefox 84.0.1(64-Bit)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, selenium-firefoxdriver, gecko

I'm trying to develop my own web scraper via Python on PyCharm but I've found I hit an issue with finding the file name of the web driver extension for Firefox. I went online to go get the version of the *zip* file but all I got was:

```
"Sorry, the page /en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver/Clients could not be found."
```

on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver/Clients which was the link used on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver/Clients under usage: "depends on which WebDriver client you’re using" link.

I'm trying to get the *zip* file of version 84.0.1(64-bit) of Firefox Browser.

Could anyone help me find this zip file?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

you can download webdriver in the above link

the compatability chart is

https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/Support.html

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The list of all the releases of [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329528/which-firefox-browser-versions-supported-for-given-geckodriver-version/45331403#45331403) can be found at [mozilla / geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)

However it is recomended to crosscheck the compattibility of the version of [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45510338/selenium-webdriver-3-4-0-geckodriver-0-18-0-firefox-which-combination-w/45510453#45510453) you are downloading as per the [matrix](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/Support.html) below:

[image: GeckoDriver_matrix]

---

### This usecase

For [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) version 84.0.1 you can use either of the following version of [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47073748/which-firefox-version-is-compatible-with-selenium-3-6-0/47095220#47095220):

- [v0.28.0](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.28.0)
- [v0.27.0](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.27.0)
- [v0.26.0](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.26.0)
- [v0.25.0](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.25.0)