# How to set up geckodriver with Selenium in google-colaboratory?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox, google-colaboratory, geckodriver

For some context, I'm using Google Collab to try to make a webscraper, and for that I want to use selenium. But I can't seem to set up the web driver properly. Google uses Ubuntu servers I believe.

This is my first time trying to selenium so I'm not sure what I'm looking for or doing wrong.

Here is the installation of selenium and geckodriver.

```
!pip install selenium
!wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.24.0/geckodriver-v0.24.0-linux64.tar.gz
!tar -xvzf geckodriver*
!chmod +x geckodriver
!sudo mv geckodriver /usr/local/bin/
```

Here is the code I'm attempting to run

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(product_link)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
```

Here is the error I'm getting.

```
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-ef677185e35a> in <cell line: 4>()
      2 product_link = base_url + links[0]
      3 
----> 4 driver = webdriver.Firefox()
      5 driver.get(product_link)
      6 driver.implicitly_wait(5)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py in assert_process_still_running(self)
    108         return_code = self.process.poll()
    109         if return_code:
--> 110             raise WebDriverException(f"Service {self._path} unexpectedly exited. Status code was: {return_code}")
    111 
    112     def is_connectable(self) -> bool:

WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/local/bin/geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```

What is status code 1 mean? The only other result I could find for the status 1 error was a reddit that's been private.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message...

```
WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/local/bin/geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```

...implies that the *GeckoDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) session.

Your main issue is the *incompatibility* between the version of the binaries as you are using as [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45331403/7429447) version ***0.24.0*** which supported Firefox ***v57*** to ***v79*** is quite *old* and *ancient* now.

So there is a clear mismatch between [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45510453/7429447) ***v0.24.0*** and the current Firefox Browser ***v114.0.2*** which is aptly supported by GeckoDriver ***v0.33.0***

---

### Solution

You need to download [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47095220/7429447) ***v0.33.0*** as:

```
!wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.33.0/geckodriver-v0.33.0-linux64.tar.gz
```

---

### References

A couple of relevant documentations:

- [GeckoDriver v0.33.0](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.33.0)
- [Supported platforms](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/Support.html)

Comment: @Spigzi Restart the workspace/system and retest.

Comment: Thank you that worked, I also had to add options which fixed it.